# Screen reader: Button or link

Tags: html, button, accessibility, anchor

I have an application that currently contains a preview link that when clicked, will load a new page that simulates what is being edited.

```
<a href="javascript://"> Preview </a>
```

The screen reader reads it as preview link, but some colleagues want it to be read as preview button. The quick fix would be to add role="button", but I know that is not good practice. I wanted to ask whether this functionality should be a button because it makes more sense to be a link

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally, buttons trigger an action, while links open pages or update a section of the current page.

Also, it's often unadvisable to  mix links and buttons in the same run, component, toolbar, or serie of items.
Elements should all be buttons or links.

These two indications should help you decide which is the best for your case.
Sadly, there is nothing more precise.

Your preview feature seem to be a little in between.
It opens a page, so should be a link; but it can also be viewed as an action within your app, in which case it should be a button.
Depending on people you ask to, you are probably going to get the two views.

At the end, it doesn't matter a lot. The most important is that the link or button is accessible, reachable with the keyboard, and usable.